# How to get the first value in JSON brackets

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that returns the following:

```
{ 'random_string': '' }
```

Where `random_string` is an id that I do not know until it is returned.
How do I extract the value of `random_string` in JS? Thank you.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Javascript, sorry should have specified

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: No, because the random_string is an id with numbers that changes on every refresh.

Comment: That's not so useful.  The idea of a property name is that you know what it is.

Comment: This needs more clarity. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = { 'random_string': '' }
console.log(Object.keys(a)[0])
```

Comment: To better help the OP, you should explain what your answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `a` has a value of type Object. Take a look at the Object prototype's documentation and see which methods are available to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

You're trying to get your object's first key, and so conveniently you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as follows:

```js
var a = { 'random_string': '' }

// Get array of Object's key values as strings
var aKeys = Object.keys(a);
console.log(aKeys);

// Print first key, in this case you only have one
console.log(aKeys[0]);
```

But based on your comments, you're going about this wrong.

If your `"random_string"` property identifier is truly random, you'd want to store the random string as an object property value.

That might look something like this:

```js
// Generate some random string value
var random = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

// Create an object with a predefined object property identifier
var data = { 'random_value': random };

// Access the random value using your known property identifier
console.log(data.random_value);
```